# How to tell users how many years they have left till 21

Tags: ruby, algorithm

What I am trying to do is tell the your how many years they have left till there 21. I have been trying to think of it but nothing.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

under_age = 21

print "What is your first name? "
first_name = gets.chomp

print "What is your last name? "
last_name = gets.chomp

print "What is your age? "
user_age = Integer(gets.chomp)

if user_age < legal_age
    print "You may not continue"
else if > 21
    print "Welcome!"
```

Answer (score 4):

You set this at the beginning:

```
under_age = 21
```

But then you don't use it, you use `legal_age` I think if you change the first line to

```
legal_age = 21
```

and then drop the last less-than like:

```
if user_age < legal_age
  years_to_wait = 21 - user_age
  print "You may not continue, come back in #{years_to_wait} year#{years_to_wait > 1? 's' : ''} "
else
  print "Welcome!"
end
```

I added a little bit there that you may have not covered being new to Ruby. Just to be clear:

`#{years_to_wait}` inside of a double quote string (" vs ') prints out as the value of the variable. If the variable is 1, then the response would be the singular "year", if greater than 1 it would be plural "years". I used the very compact version of if/then/else to make it clean (called the Ternary operator).

The first part is the comparison followed by the ? for an implied "if"

```
years_to_wait > 1?
```

followed by the return value if true which is the character 's' then a ":" and the return value if false, no character ''. That gets us the correct version of the word "year(s)" when the interpolation happens.

Comment: Wow I was just thinking about how to do that exact same thing with the "s" just incase the user types 20. Can you explain the bit beginning at the year#{years_to_wait > 1?}......

Comment: LOL was just typing an explanation when that came in. Does that make sense? Anything in `#{   }` gets interpolated at runtime. So you can do pretty much any operation in there. I'm using the ternary operator.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the code! I do understand now. Could you use a regular if statement there? Just curious.

Comment: @Beartech Great answer with explanations to help give the OP an understanding of how to understand the reasoning in the answer.  Love it!

Answer (score 1):

Your variable names are all over the place. But I think you just want

```
legal_age - user_age
```

Also your last if is unnessary

Comment: Oh ok you mean put an else instead of an elsif?

Comment: @Scope Yeah because the if handles the case when they are less than 21 which means the else is 21 or older. So it would be redundant to have another if. Also your second if should have been >= 21. Otherwise people who are exactly 21 would not get any message

Comment: Oh ok, yeah that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the variable in the elsif statement in ruby it should look:

```
if user_age < 21
    print "You may not continue"
elsif user_age > 21
    print "Welcome!"
end
```

the legal_age variable is also not assigned, maybe you mean the under_age variable instead.

Comment: Thank! Yeah I should have known that by now.

Answer (score 0):

your `if..else` syntax is not proper. for **[more info](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm)**

```
if user_age < under_age
    print "You may not continue, come back after #{under_age - user_age} years"
else
    print "Welcome!"
end
```

**Note:** `legal_age` is also not assigned, you can replace it with `under_age` or change `under_age` to `legal_age`